# How I navigate using slider keyboard in Windows phone Applications? How it implementing only using xaml?

Tags: windows-phone-7

can I navigate using slider keyboard in Windows phone Applications? How it implementing only using xaml?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The Windows Phone 7 keyboard can only be used to provide input for text fields, it cannot be shown on demand or used for keypress events.

Also, in order to be certified by the Windows Marketplace you must follow the navigation requirements, which mandate the use of the hardware back-button.